# Update rows in Oracle in reference to other table rows

Tags: oracle10g

Hi Guys I am trying to Update some rows like this :

```
declare
   cursor c1 is select core_cust_id, ADDRESS_LINE1, ADDRESS_LINE2, ADDRESS_LINE3,CITY_CODE,
   STATE_CODE from crmuser.address where corp_id is not null and 
ADDRESSCATEGORY='Mailing';
   begin
   for i in c1 loop
   update  crmuser.tradefinance set ADDR_1=i.ADDRESS_LINE1,
   ADDR_2=i.ADDRESS_LINE2, ADDR_3=i.ADDRESS_LINE3, CITY_CODE=i.CITY_CODE,
   STATE_CODE=i.STATE_CODE       
   where i.core_cust_id=(select core_cust_id from crmuser.tradefinance where corp_id is not null);
   end loop; 
   end;
```

i am getting the Error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

When I execute

```
select core_cust_id, ADDRESS_LINE1, ADDRESS_LINE2, ADDRESS_LINE3,CITY_CODE,
   STATE_CODE from crmuser.address where corp_id is not null and 
ADDRESSCATEGORY='Mailing';
```

I get 485 records with Which I want to Match the Core_cust_id. When I execute:

```
select core_cust_id from crmuser.tradefinance where corp_id is not null;
```

I again get the 485 core_cust Ids to Match the other Core_cust_ids in the Loop...Why is my query returning Multiple records? What should I correct? I am Using Oracle 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
declare
   cursor c1 is select core_cust_id, ADDRESS_LINE1, ADDRESS_LINE2, ADDRESS_LINE3,CITY_CODE,
   STATE_CODE from crmuser.address where corp_id is not null and 
ADDRESSCATEGORY='Mailing';
   begin
   for i in c1 loop
   update  crmuser.tradefinance set ADDR_1=i.ADDRESS_LINE1,
   ADDR_2=i.ADDRESS_LINE2, ADDR_3=i.ADDRESS_LINE3, CITY_CODE=i.CITY_CODE,
   STATE_CODE=i.STATE_CODE       
   where i.core_cust_id=crmuser.tradefinance.core_cust_id 
   and crmuser.corp_id is not null;
   end loop; 
   end;
```

Comment: Thanks hktulay but had to edit some bit `where i.core_cust_id = tradefinance.core_cust_id and tradefinance.corp_id is not null` towards the end....CRMUSER is the schema not the table name.